# dual kd-tree construction

Tags: java, kdtree

Please anyone tell me how to construct dual `kd-tree` and how to traverse it?

And at least tell me the algorithm for finding `nearest neighbor` using this dual tree concept in `java`. This will help full for my project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can read Python, look at the clear source for `query_ball_tree` described in
[scipy.spatial.KDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.9.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html),
"Find all pairs of points whose distance is at most r". (Is that what you want to do ?)

Comment: Thank you for replay and also please help me finding balanced kd-tree java code. Present code i have is not balanced. Also comment is any tree which is efficient than kdtree

Comment: Sorry, can't help on java; did you find the python query_ball_tree (65 lines) understandable ?  Re other trees / kdtree variants, you'll have to be more specific. See also [nearest-neighbors-in-high-dimensional-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751114/nearest-neighbors-in-high-dimensional-data).